# User and ROles (how can i handle this?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

In my view, I'd like to add a User to a role using checkboxes. I list all the roles then check two or three to add the user to that role. How do I handle this?

Comment: your question is not clear.. Can you please show us some code and tell us what you expect.. what you have tried till now..

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your post...

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserDetails(UserClass user, bool admin, bool superAdmin, bool GodRole)
    {
        MembershipUser muser = Membership.GetUser(user.UserName);
        if (admin)
            Roles.AddUserToRole(muser.UserName, "admin");
        if (superAdmin)
            Roles.AddUserToRole(muser.UserName, "superAdmin");
        if (GodRole)
            Roles.AddUserToRole(muser.UserName, "GodRole");
        return View();
    }
```

Hope this helps...